# add axis scale to plot

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need to add a scale to this graphic from -3 to 3 on the x axis with an increase of 1 unit and from -1.5 to 1.5 to the y axis with an increase of 0.5 units.
The code is the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \begin{document}
      \begin{tikzpicture}[domain=-3:3, range=-3:3]
        \draw[very thin,color=gray] (-3,+3);
        \draw[->] (-3,0) -- (3,0) node[right] {$x$}; 
        \draw[->] (0,-1.5) -- (0,1.5) node[above] {$y$};
        \draw[color=red] plot (\x,1)  node[right] {$f(x) =1$}; 
        \draw[color=blue] plot (\x,{cos(\x r)}) node[right] {$f(x) = \cos x$};
        \draw[color=blue] plot (\x, {1 -\x*\x/2}) node[right] {$f(x) = 1- \frac{x^2}{2}$};
      \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the following lines:

```
\foreach \x in {-3,...,3}{0    \draw (\x,0) node {$|$} node [yshift=-0.3cm]{$\x$};}
\foreach \x in {-1.5,-1,-0.5,0,0.5,1,1.5}{0    \draw (0,\x)  node {$-$} node [xshift=-0.3cm]{$\x$};}
```

you can change the x and y shifts to make it look better

Comment: it is pretty good, but the numbers tend to overlap